# Why would reads block other reads in Aurora PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, aws-aurora, amazon-rds-aurora

We're running an AWS Aurora PostgreSQL version 13 database.  The other day, I was trying to set up a backup job to run from the read replica, and I ended up encountering the error "User was holding a relation lock for too long."  I worked around it using the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592436/postgresql-error-canceling-statement-due-to-conflict-with-recovery?rq=3).

My question is theoretical, and forgive me if it sounds stupid, but I'm missing something here.  If Postgres has MVCC instead of locking, why would pg_dump care about a user "locking" another relation?  Shouldn't it just be reading the last version of the row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about table locks and streaming replication conflicts. My answer is about PostgreSQL and will apply to Amazon Aurora only to the (unknown) extent that it behaves like PostgreSQL.

`pg_dump` has to read the tables, and reading a table requires an `ACCESS SHARE` lock on the table. Such a lock conflicts only with activities like `DROP TABLE`, `TRUNCATE`, `CLUSTER`, `VACUUM (FULL)` and certain variants of `ALTER TABLE`. An `ACCESS SHARE` lock does not block writers, it prevents concurrent sessions from deleting the data file you are currently reading.

Now if you have a long running query like `pg_dump` on the standby and somebody `TRUNCATE`s a table on the primary, PostgreSQL will try to replay the statement and the associated `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the standby. This will conflict with the long running query, and if `pg_dump` is not done after `max_standby_streaming_delay` has passed, the query is canceled and `pg_dump` terminates with an error.

Note that the conflicts need not be with one of the above statements: if autovacuum processes a table on the primary, and the last couple of pages in the table become empty, `VACUUM` will try to remove these pages, which also requires a brief `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table. This does not disrupt processing on the primary, but may lead to queries being canceled on the standby.

Set `max_standby_streaming_delay` to -1 on the standby server to avoid the problem.

[Here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/streaming-replication-conflicts-in-postgresql/) is an article that deals with the problem in more detail.

Comment: How is the `max_standby_streaming_delay` implemented internally? Is there a some kind of fair queue when new read-only queries wait for apply, or we may get a situation when the apply fails to promote itself due to large stream of read-only queries?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Interesting question. I just tested it, and locks will queue as usual: a query that starts running on the standby after the startup process has started to wait for the lock to apply a `TRUNCATE` gets blocked. So a steady stream of queries won't block replication forever, only until all queries that started before the lock are done.